# Filter ClientDataSet by more than one Field

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

The following code allows me to filter a clientdataset by one field:

```
begin
dmodule.cds.DisableControls;
try
  dmodule.cds.Filtered := False;

  dmodule.cds.FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive,foNoPartialCompare];
  dmodule.cds.Filter := 'Field LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+ editSearch.Text + '%');

  dmodule.cds.Filtered := True;
finally
  dmodule.cds.EnableControls;
end;
```

I have added in another line after the first 'cds.Filter' line which I thought would allow me to filter by another field but it doesn't bring back any records.

The line is:

```
dmodule.cds.Filter := 'Field2 LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+ editSearch.Text + '%');
```

Do I need to do something else to allow multiple filtering?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just combine them  with `and` (you can also use `or` if need be):

```
begin
  dmodule.cds.DisableControls;
  try
    dmodule.cds.Filtered := False;

    dmodule.cds.FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive,foNoPartialCompare];
    dmodule.cds.Filter := 'Field LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+ editSearch.Text + '%') +
                          'AND Field2 LIKE ' + QuotedStr(editSearch2.Text) + '%');


    dmodule.cds.Filtered := True;
  finally
    dmodule.cds.EnableControls;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second line basically ***replaces*** the filter in the first line.  You probably want:

```
dmodule.cds.Filter := 
         'Field LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+ editSearch.Text + '%') + 
     ' OR Field2 LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+ editSearch.Text + '%');
```

Note: I've assumed you want OR because you were surprised about not returning any data. Of course if you require both conditions to be True to return data, then use AND; but you'll still get no records.